# Request for member which is of non-class type void*

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, interface

I am trying to do a pointer to generic object type of thing but i don't get how to access the arbitrary object method.

I tried definining an interface

```
class InterfaceProtocol{
    public:
    virtual void accessBlock(unsigned long int address, unsigned long int size, bool read) = 0;
};
```

Which i inherit in another class

```
class SACache : public InterfaceProtocol{
    void* next
    virtual void accessBlock(unsigned long int address, unsigned long int size, bool read);
}
```

At a certain point i want the last class to access a generic object using the accessBlock function inherited from InterfaceProtocol

```
void SACache::accessBlock(unsigned long int address, unsigned long int size, bool read){
   next.accessBlock(blockAddress,blockSize,YES);
}
```

I'm really new in object oriented stuff but as far as i'm concerned a template would not be necesarry here mainly because i can guarantee that the generic object will also inherit the InterfaceProtocol methods.

Comment: What is `next` supposed to be used for? Can't you use the actual class? Either as a template or through inheritance and polymorphism?

Comment: next is supposed to be another class (not the same of course) that has also inherited the interface protocol methods, what i want is to be able to define next as a generic class

Comment: Re. `"...another class (not the same of course) that has also inherited the interface protocol methods"`: then rather than `void *` you should use a pointer to the actual type that declares those interface methods, right?  An [mcve] would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` is a `void*` which means it's a pointer to absolutely anything, like an `int`. If you want it to always point to an `InterfaceProtocol` then write `InterfaceProtocol* next;`.

And, `next` is a pointer. The thing it points to is `*next`. If you want to call function on the thing it points to, write `(*next).accessBlock` or for short `next->accessBlock`.

Comment: The thing is, Interface protocol is just that, an arbitrary class that will be inherited by another class (that is why i can't use InterfaceProtocol* next), what i need is to define "next" as a pointer to a generic class. Trying to access the object as (*next).accessBlock() results in a not pointer-to-object type.

Comment: @HansCarrizales What resources are you using to learn C++? What have they told you about inheritance and *polymorphism*? If you have e.g. `class ActualProtocol : public InterfaceProtocol { ... };` then remember that inheritance is an **is-a** relationship. Objects of type `ActualProtocol` are *also* of the type `InterfaceProtocol`. So you can do e.g. `InterfaceProtocol* protocol = new ActualProtocol;` and use `protocol->accessBlock(...)` and the `ActualProtocol::accessBlock` function will be called.

Comment: @HansCarrizales If you don't have any decent books, now might be a good time invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).